# "vagrant up" ok but can't access via browser

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying Vagrant for first time on OSX Yosemite and downloaded Vagrantfile/Cheffile from http://rove.io with LAMP stack.

Here they are:

**cheffile**

```
# encoding: utf-8

site 'http://community.opscode.com/api/v1'

cookbook "apt"
cookbook "mysql", {}
cookbook "nodejs", {:github=>"mdxp/nodejs-cookbook"}
cookbook "python", {}
cookbook "git", {}
cookbook "php", {}
cookbook "nginx", {}
```

**vagrantfile**

```
# encoding: utf-8
# This file originally created at http://rove.io/36f03d7ed905b30118b48bfe3d16ee07

# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.4.0"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.4.0.box"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe :apt
    chef.add_recipe 'mysql::server'
    chef.add_recipe 'nodejs'
    chef.add_recipe 'python'
    chef.add_recipe 'git'
    chef.add_recipe 'php'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx'
    chef.json = {
      :mysql => {
        :server_root_password   => "password",
        :server_repl_password   => "password",
        :server_debian_password => "password",
        :service_name           => "mysql",
        :basedir                => "/usr",
        :data_dir               => "/var/lib/mysql",
        :root_group             => "root",
        :mysqladmin_bin         => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin",
        :mysql_bin              => "/usr/bin/mysql",
        :conf_dir               => "/etc/mysql",
        :confd_dir              => "/etc/mysql/conf.d",
        :socket                 => "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",
        :pid_file               => "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid",
        :grants_path            => "/etc/mysql/grants.sql"
      },
      :git   => {
        :prefix => "/usr/local"
      },
      :nginx => {
        :dir                => "/etc/nginx",
        :log_dir            => "/var/log/nginx",
        :binary             => "/usr/sbin/nginx",
        :user               => "www-data",
        :init_style         => "runit",
        :pid                => "/var/run/nginx.pid",
        :worker_connections => "1024"
      }
    }
  end
end
```

So, then I tried get this up:

```
$ librarian-chef install
$ vagrant up

➜  myapp git:(master) ✗ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.
➜  myapp git:(master) ✗ vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
Skipping Berkshelf with --no-provision
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.12
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/myuser/projects/dev
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks => /Users/myuser/projects/dev/cookbooks
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I guess it's working, right?

I'm trying http://127.0.0.1 on Chrome and it says not found.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "not found" means the vagrant machine is running fine, browser can connect to the server, you just don't have any documents in the document root or the file you try to access doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

You need to access via the ip of vm box using following steps.

ssh to vagrant box

```
vagrant ssh

$ ifconfig
```

copy the id and open in browser. IP should be something like 192.168.1.5 and in browser, open http://192.168.1.5:8080

Answer (score -2):

Try to destroy it and start it again. Show us the logs if it doesn't help:

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

You can always log into VM with ssh and check what went wrong:

```
vagrant ssh
```